# There can be only one auto column

Tags: mysql, ddl

How do I correct the error from MySQL 'you can only have one auto increment column'.

```
CREATE TABLE book (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   accepted_terms BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   accepted_privacy BIT(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The full error message sounds:

> ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

So add `primary key` to the `auto_increment` field:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key NOT NULL,
   accepted_terms BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   accepted_privacy BIT(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 175):

My MySQL says "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column **and it must be defined as a key**" So when I added primary key as below it started working:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   accepted_terms BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   accepted_privacy BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What is the correct course of action if the column is part of a composite key?

Comment: What is the syntax when altering the table?

Comment: @MikeHarrison looks like you can just put 

`ALTER TABLE book ADD id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);`

Answer (score 25):

Note also that "key" does not necessarily mean *primary* key.  Something like this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    isbn             BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    id               INT    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    accepted_terms   BIT(1) NOT NULL,
    accepted_privacy BIT(1) NOT NULL,
    INDEX(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is a contrived example and probably not the best idea, but it can be very useful in certain cases.

Comment: This helped me in a situation where I wanted to define a composite key for easy updating but I also wanted to have an auto-incrementing ID for debugging purposes. Is there anything I should be aware of in terms of risk, apart from slightly slower writes possibly?

Comment: @Mattias No, I don't believe there's any particular risk.  This is intentionally supported, with the auto column being the primary key purely by convention (and for simplicity).

Comment: You can also use UNIQUE key, or any other key listed here - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65fc13/working-with-keys-in-mysql/#:~:text=In%20MySQL%2C%20a%20key%20is,from%20a%20table%20as%20needed.

Comment: This gives me "Multiple primary key defined"

Comment: Unlikely, since there's only one primary key.  Works just fine here on 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0 @AlxVallejo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da0a4b0797a16f3ff0368d6a68f5ab30

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE book (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key NOT NULL,
   accepted_terms BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   accepted_privacy BIT(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens with you because in the case that you didn't create a primary key, SEQUELIZE will automatically generate a primary key with a default name `id`. Which causes a duplication because you already created one and SEQUELIZE created one too.
But when you defined `id` as a primary key. SEQUELIZE didn't create the default `id` primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a solution that helped me. In case there is a multi-column primary key, the following would generate the same error:

```sql
CREATE TABLE book (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   accepted_terms BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   accepted_privacy BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (accepted_terms, id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But the following works fine (=note the ordering of the `PRIMARY KEY`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE book (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   accepted_terms BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   accepted_privacy BIT(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, accepted_terms)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```