# Equivalent of MSSQL IDENTITY Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, identity

What is the equivalent of MSSQL `IDENTITY` Columns in MySQL? How would I create this table in MySQL?

```
CREATE TABLE Lookups.Gender
(
    GenderID   INT         IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    GenderName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: If only MySQL provided some type of [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: true @JohnFx, although personally I'd prefer to go to StackOverflow than that site from my googling.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Lookups.Gender
(
    GenderID   INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GenderName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer hope could pay you back :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me (5.6.10; this is Aurora but syntax should work identically): `SQL Error (1075): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`.

Comment: @mbourgon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645889/there-can-be-only-one-auto-column

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE `Persons` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This above example uses the `AUTO_INCREMENT` syntax. You can specify a starting offset specific to the table.

The *Increment*, however, has to be set globally.

**`SET @@auto_increment_increment=10;`**

You can also set a global default for the offset like follows:

**`SET @@auto_increment_offset=5;`**

To view your current values, type **`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';`**