# Duplicate Entry for Primary Key

Tags: mysql

The task given is:

> Create a new relational table to store information about the company names of all suppliers and the total number of products supplied by each supplier. Enforce, the appropriate consistencyconstraints on the new table. Next, copy into the new table information about the company names of all suppliers and the total number of products supplied by each supplier.

I'm recieving an error `Duplicate Entry for key "PRIMARY"` When i try and run this script

```
     CREATE TABLE COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS (

        COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY',
        PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY' ,
        TOTAL_PRODUCTS VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EMPTY',
        CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(COMPANY_NAME) ,
        CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY_NAME) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(COMPANY_NAME)


        );

    INSERT INTO COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS(COMPANY_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME)
    SELECT  DISTINCT SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME, PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME
    FROM SUPPLIER, PRODUCT;

    UPDATE COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS
    SET TOTAL_PRODUCTS = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALPRODUCTS
    FROM PRODUCT);
```

The Whole purpose of the exercise is to copy company names of all suppliers and the total number of products supplied by each supplier.

TABLES GIVEN

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER
(
    COMPANY_NAME    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    CONTACT_NAME    VARCHAR(30),
    CONTACT_TITLE   VARCHAR(30),
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(60),
    CITY        VARCHAR(15),
    REGION      VARCHAR(15),
    POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR(10),
    COUNTRY         VARCHAR(15),
    PHONE       VARCHAR(24),
    FAX         VARCHAR(24),
    HOME_PAGE       VARCHAR(500),
    CONSTRAINT PK_SUPPLIER PRIMARY KEY (COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
    PRODUCT_NAME    VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    SUPPLIER_NAME   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY_NAME   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY_PER_UNIT   VARCHAR(20),
    UNIT_PRICE      DECIMAL(10,2)   NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    UNITS_IN_STOCK  DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    UNITS_ON_ORDER  DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0, 
    REORDER_LEVEL   DECIMAL(9)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    DISCONTINUED    CHAR(1)     NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'N',
    CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCT PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CATEGORY_NAME FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_NAME) REFERENCES CATEGORY(CATEGORY_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER_NAME FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_NAME) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(COMPANY_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE CHECK (UNIT_PRICE >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNITS_IN_STOCK CHECK (UNITS_IN_STOCK >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_UNITS_ON_ORDER CHECK (UNITS_ON_ORDER >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_REORDER_LEVEL CHECK (REORDER_LEVEL >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT CK_PRODUCT_DISCONTINUED CHECK (DISCONTINUED in ('Y','N'))
);
```

Comment: Oh, it does. It's producing **distinct rows**, not distinct `COMPANY_NAME`. Revisit your solution.

Comment: @TheImpaler does it make a difference that theres no duplicates?

Comment: So every supplier can supply every product? That's what the `INSERT` statement does with `SUPPLIER, PRODUCT`. Its also odd naming where TOTAL_PRODUCTS is the total of all the products. Why is TOTAL_PRODUCTS as `VARCHAR` instead of a numeric type. Suggest using "NULL", instead of the defaults string 'EMPTY' if you need not filled table values.

Comment: @danblack Yes Many Suppliers Can Supplier Many products. In regards to the empty defaults, if i dont do this it says they need a default value.

Comment: Your `COMPANY_AND_SUPPLIERS` table has `COMPANY_NAME` as a primary key, i.e. each company can only appear once but your `INSERT` implies there should be a row for each product + company meaning more than one row per company. What is the intent of this table?

Comment: @AndrewVan That's because you declare them `NOT NULL`, so you can't use `NULL` as the default value.

Comment: @danblack but my main issue is how do only make company names distinct then. It shouldnt be returning duplicate values as theres only one of each name.

Comment: The primary key should probably be composite `(COMPANY_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME)`, to allow a company to sell multiple products.

Comment: @AndrewVan You're duplicating the company name for each product. You have `Company1 Product1, Company1 Product2, Company1 Product3, Company2 Product1, Company2 Product2, Company2 Product3, ...`

Comment: If that's not what you want, which single product should it list for each company?

Comment: @smashed-potatoes "Create a new relational table to store information about the company names  of all suppliers and the total number of products supplied by each supplier. Enforce, the appropriate consistencyconstraints on the new table. Next, copy into the new table information about the company names of all suppliers and the total number of products supplied by each supplier.*

Comment: You're supposed to have two tables. One is the relational table between companies and products, it can have multiple rows for each company. The second is a table just for companies, it has one row for each company, and just the total number of products, not the product names.

Comment: @Barmar yes the relational table between companies and products is the one i created.

Comment: That table shouldn't have `COMPANY_NAME` as the primary key. Only the `COMPANY` table should be like that. And this table shouldn't have `TOTAL_PRODUCTS`, that should be in the `COMPANY` table.

Comment: @Barmar they give us a table for the supplier and the product if that helps

Comment: @Barmar so how would i store the total number of products then? I thought you'd have to make a new Column to do this

Comment: @AndrewVan Oh yes, big time.

Answer (score 0):

Your table isn't supposed to contain the product names, just the company and total products. The `PRODUCTS` table already has the supplier names in it for each product. So you just need to count the number of products for each supplier from that table.

```
CREATE TABLE Company_Totals (
    Company_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Total_Products INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Company_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (Company_name) REFERENCES Supplier(Company_name)
);

INSERT INTO Company_Totals (Company_name, Total_Products)
SELECT SUPPLIER_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM PRODUCT
GROUP BY SUPPLIER_NAME;
```

Comment: yea they give us a Product Table and a Supplier Table. The Product table doesn't have a Company Name but the supplier table does.  @Barmar

Comment: i tried doing your query but the total count comes up as 1 for all the products. @Barmar

Comment: They need to give you a third table that links products and suppliers.

Comment: Please see my edit i added the two tables given @Barmar

Comment: The `PRODUCT` table you're given is the table I'm talking about. It has both the company name and product name.

Comment: EDIT I did it thankyou so much for your help @Barmar. Apologies if i sound clueless, im still fairly new to sql and im struggling to interpurate the questions that im given

Comment: just another quick question. Is this similar to what i just did? "Add to a relational table EMPLOYEE information about the total number of orders
handled by each employee" @Barmar

Comment: That sounds similar.

Comment: Would i just be adding a Column to Employee for the total Number? @Barmar

Comment: That sounds like what they're asking you to do. Then you need to do an `UPDATE` with `JOIN` to get the count for each employee.

Comment: If you have trouble getting that to work, you need to ask a new question, we're not going to solve this in comments.

Comment: Okay ill do so and then link it here. Ive attempted the question with a working sccript but im unsure if its correct @Barmar

Comment: hello @Barmar. I actually figured the question out! but theres one i am extremely stuck on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184370/how-to-delete-from-a-table-without-having-to-drop-a-constraint

Answer (score 0):

The column `company_name` should not be a `primary key` because a `primary key` is a unique value.

Take this as an example

If a Database administrator creates a table with `first_name` as the primary key, it would be a disaster since there are a lot of people who has John as their first name

That is why most of the time, the primary key is a integer, then we make it unique using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10283830/1801763) method.